# How to use His/My/Your permutations in adressing persons

Tags: style, fiction, technical-writing, creative-writing, fantasy

I'd like to understand the rationale of when, why and how His/My/Your are used in titles of addressing people.

For example, the standard commonly accepted uses are:

- "His Honour"("His Grace", or "Her" instead of "His") in written while "Your Honour" ("Your Grace") verbally;
  while
- "His Lordship" in written while "My Lord" orally;

The interest is twofold:

- to grasp mnemonics, i.e. how to remember as to avoid wrong use (especially oral one when I cannot consult before using);
- how to use such addressing in possible non-standard (metaphorical, satirical, mockering) transformations preserving continuity of a chosen style

Why  (and when) are such differences between:

- "His"/"Her" and "Your" (horizontally, using, for example, with "Grace" )
- "His Grace"(or "Her") and "My" Lord" (vertically, in verbal usage)

How should I have transformed above phrases in context of:

- "Disgrace" or "Shame" (instead of "Grace")
- or "Dishonour" (instead of "Honour")
  ?

Comment: My Lord! You cannot recognize His Lordship? May His Grace be with you!

Comment: A marvelous question, but is this better suited for EL&U?

Comment: @Lauren Ipsum, nice username. I gonna steal it. Can you copy it to EL&U? I have 1000-day ban there. Thanks

Comment: Don't tell me, you are asking here, because you are suspended on EL. Muahahahah!

Comment: @John Smithers, I understand, it is should be easy when English is one's native language...

Comment: Ok, let us close this thing and move it to EL. I wonder what will happen. There was a case like this before on Meta.SO, but I totally forgot what the result was.

Comment: The only interesting thing left: Why were you suspended?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102293/block-migration-if-user-is-suspended-question-blocked-at-destination is marked as completed; if I understand correctly, migration will be blocked.